# Weird voice streaming and receiving audio through UDP

Tags: java, udp, javasound

I was implementing two programs in Java, one sends through UDP the output audio and another one receives it and play it.

### Weird behavior:

While executing both programs (they communicate via loopback address), the only thing you can sometimes (every 10 seconds) hear  is a voice (apparently of a woman) saying "ciao".

The first time I heard it I was quite scared but now I am really curios to understand when this audio bytes come from.

### Receiver code

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("connect to " + Inet4Address.getLocalHost().toString() + " on port " + port);
    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1280];  //1280!!!!!!
    // ( 1280 for 16 000Hz and 3584 for 44 100Hz (use AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat) to get the correct size)
    format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);
    while (status == true) {
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                receiveData.length);
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                receivePacket.getData());
        ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());
        // A thread solve the problem of chunky audio 
        new Thread(() -> {
            toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());
        }).start();
    }
}

public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
    try {

        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

        sourceDataLine.open(format);

        FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) sourceDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        volumeControl.setValue(6.0f);

        sourceDataLine.start();
        sourceDataLine.open(format);

        sourceDataLine.start();

        System.out.println("format? :" + sourceDataLine.getFormat());

        sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
        //     System.out.println(soundbytes.toString());
        sourceDataLine.drain();
        sourceDataLine.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### Stream Code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        AudioFormat.Encoding encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
        float rate = 16000.0f;
        int channels = 1;
        int sampleSize = 16;
        boolean bigEndian = false;
        InetAddress addr;

        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(rate, sampleSize, channels, true, bigEndian);
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            System.out.println("Line matching " + info + " not supported.");
            return;
        }

        tdl = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        tdl.open(format);
        tdl.start();

        socket = new DatagramSocket();

        buffer = new byte[tdl.getBufferSize() / 5];

        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        //   hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.43.1");
        hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName("172.19.0.238");

    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AudioSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AudioSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    (new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                while (true) {
                    int s = tdl.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket
                            = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, hostAddress, port);
                    socket.send(sendPacket);
                    System.out.println(">>>" + sendPacket.getData());
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AudioSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    })).start();
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"a voice (apparently of a woman) saying "ciao"."* ..have you consumed any mind altering substances recently?

Comment: No I don't use any substances except for coffeine (which could be already enough for allucination). I found the answer. Few months ago i have installer the driver "Virtual Audio Cable" which """apparently""" the FREE version says 'TRIAL' every 15 seconds to get you buy it. The problem is that i am Italian and i have the word 'ciao' inside my heart and second, i don't know english pronuntiation so for me was impossible to understand 'trial'. 
I am glad i found it out.

Comment: Ah .. the dreaded English. Glad you sorted that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
DatagramPacket sendPacket
                        = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, hostAddress, port);
```

The first problem is here. You're ignoring the length. It should be:

```
DatagramPacket sendPacket
                        = new DatagramPacket(buffer, s, hostAddress, port);
```

You're also ignoring end of stream. If `s` was -1 you should break out of the loop. Then:

```
ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            receivePacket.getData());
```

The second problem is here. You're ignoring the length. It should be:

```
ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            receivePacket.getData(), receivePacket.getOffset(), receivePacket.getLength());
```

Comment: Ok but how can i explay the weird voice?

Comment: The weird voice is because you're ignoring the length variable in all the three ways I specified in my answer, which means you're processing junk data in each datagram. When you fix these errors I should certainly hope it wouldn't work the same.